# How to paste data in Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to implement a modal that will take OTP for mobile verification.
I have managed to come this far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("input", "input[id^=digit]", function(e) {
    var text = $(this).val();
     if (text.length == 6) {
      for (i=1 ; i<=text.length ; i++) {
        $("input[id^=digit]").eq(i-1).val(text[i-1]);
       }
     }
     else if (text.length > 1) {
      $(this).val(text[0]);
     }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal" id="verify_phone_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header pb-0">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body pt-0">
        <div class="profile-verification">
          <p class="verification-description">
          </p>
          <div class="verification-code-input-group d-flex">
            <input type="text" class="form-control otp_box" id="digit1" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" class="form-control otp_box" id="digit2" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" class="form-control otp_box" id="digit3" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" class="form-control otp_box" id="digit4" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" class="form-control otp_box" id="digit5" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
            <input type="text" class="form-control otp_box" id="digit6" maxlength="1" placeholder="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-error">
            <span class="help-block hidden" id="phone_number_verification_error"></span>
          </div>
          <p class="verification-description has-action-item mt-4">
            
            <span role="button" class="btn-resend">
              
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="action-row">
          <div class="action-item">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have followed [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pnNjH/3) to get going.
I am unable to find the mistake I'm making here.
Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried it from my side and written the below code.it's working fine for me.

In your code, you have set maxlength as 1, so only 1 char will be typed in the textbox when you pest the text, so only else part will be executed every time. Just remove maxlength from input, your code also will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).on("input", "input[name='chars']", function(e) {
                var text = $(this).val();
                if (text.length == 6) {
                    for (i=1 ; i<=text.length ; i++) {
                        $("#chars"+i).val(text[i-1]);
                    }    
                }
                else if (text.length > 1) {
                    $(this).val(text[0]);
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Test</h1>
        <input type='text' name='chars' id='chars1' />
        <input type='text' name='chars' id='chars2' />
        <input type='text' name='chars' id='chars3' />
        <input type='text' name='chars' id='chars4' />
        <input type='text' name='chars' id='chars5' />
        <input type='text' name='chars' id='chars6' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is what I have mentioned as a reference, where it's working.But not in my code.

Comment: please run the snippet and pest code of 6 digits.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pnNjH/3 This was the snippet I was following which was working already but when I'm trying to implement in my code, it's not working.

Comment: Your code is not working because you are working with id not with name

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yeor45ha/ This snippet is working with id only but not in my actual code.

Comment: @JackSparrow ,  As you have set max length as 1, so only 1 char will be typed in the text box when you pest the text, so only else part will be executed every time.

Comment: Got it working thanks again for the help.